# Trying to create script to update event names

Tags: javascript, replace, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am subscribed to a calendar and sometimes instead of the ' sign it shows `&#39;`
I tried to make a script that gets the next 100 events (because getting all events doesn't seem to exist in Google Apps script). This works, I can see the events in the log. Now my question is, after it gets these events, how do I make it replace the title?
what I have for now is this:

```
function listNext100Events() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 100
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
      if (event.start.date) {
        // All-day event.
        var start = parseDate(event.start.date);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
      } else {
        var start = parseDate(event.start.dateTime);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleString());
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
}
```

Also I know that the function to replace a title is

```
title.replaceText("&#39;", "'");
```

How do I combine this knowledge into a working script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your structure, I'm assuming that the title you're referring to is stored in the event.title attribute. If that's the case, this should work for replacing all instances (using regex because a regular string.replace only gets the first instance)

```
event.title = event.title.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
```